# How to pass data from a form to controller in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

How do I pass data from a form to controller and then pass it on that data to a model

```
public function registertest()
    {

    if (!empty($this->data)) {

        var_dump($this->data);

        if ($this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['cpassword'])) {
            $this->User->create();

            if($this->User->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Auth->login($this->data);
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        }
    }
    //$this->render('register');
}
```

Comment: What u need ? pls explain

Comment: Have you done [the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Code

```
 public function registertest()
    {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
       $this->data['User']['password'] == $this->Auth->password($this->data['User']['cpassword']);
       $this->User->create();

        if($this->User->save($this->request->data['User'])) {
            $this->Auth->login($this->request->data['User']);

            $msg = '<div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong> User Created succeesfully </strong>
            </div>';
            $this->Session->setFlash($msg);
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }



        }
}
```

Comment: There should never be html in a controller - this also doesn't appear to answer the question (which is unclear).